# How to silent print in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, printing, printer

Chrome Version 70.0.3538.67 (Official Build) (64-bit)

I created a shortcut which has the following target value:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --args --disable-print-preview --kiosk-printing "https://google.com"
```

Now when doing CTRL + P (or go into the menu and click "Print") a different popup (different from the original) shows up:

[image]

How can I disable this popup from appearing?

1. As you can see, the printer is set as default
2. I went to the printer properties and tried without success to check the option "Print to printer directly"

Comment: Try this: In `about:flags` disable Print preview instead of by parameter, also add both parameters ` --kiosk-printing --kiosk`.

Comment: @harrymc tried that, problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue, found that if you disable “Enable new Print Preview UI”, it will work as it used to. Still can't find any official bug tracker or update logs about this.

P.S. we try to disable updates in Chrome for our kiosks, ggl tends to break their products every now and then..